# Windows 7 Regional wallpaper packs: Where in the world?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization

Is there a list somewhere of the geographical location of the Windows 7 wallpapers?

I'd love to know more about some of these places, but apart from the region they're bundled with, there's not much information I can find.  Any hints?

Comment: It's not exactly the list you want, but [InterfaceLIFT](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper/downloads/date/any/) has wallpapers from many geographical locations, and each is accompanied by a brief description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to:

> C:\Windows\Globalization\MCT

You can see each regional wallpaper pack, there are five (5) packs, from Australia (AU), Canda (CA), Great Britain (GB), United States (US), South Africa (ZA).

In Windows 7, **right-click** on any photo inside the wallpaper packs, **select** `Properties`, and a **dialog box** will appear.  **Go to** the `Details` tab, under `Description`, there will be a `Title` field, which **tells you about the photo and where it was taken.**  Other details are in the tab, like who took the photo, the dimensions, etc.

For example, for this photo:
[image]

the `Details` tab of `Properties` looks like this:
[image]

To see more of the title, put your cursor where the red circle is, and drag it to expand the field.

This particular photo has a short title, others will have longer ones.  So you know this photo is from Australia, **just Bing** `Kimberley Plateau` and **you'll have your location.**

Answer (score 3):

I just found a temporary solution: Google's new "search by image" function.

I'll just use this to hunt down the ones I want.

However, it would be a great post for a blog if someone was to do all of them, since apparently a full list is hard to find.